# Karush-Kuhn-Tucker in infinite horizon

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Does the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker theorem on sufficient conditions for optimality of a convex program apply for a series, i.e. in countable dimension?

For precisions, see Definition 4.1.1 and Theorem 4.1.4 of [this course](https://ljk.imag.fr/membres/Anatoli.Iouditski/cours/convex/chapitre_4.pdf). Does the theorem extend to an infinite (but discrete) number of variables and associated constraints? If so, do you have a reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [Bachir et al. (2021)](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s43036-020-00125-y) extend the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker theorem under mild hypotheses, for a countable number of variables (in their Corollary 4.1).

I give hereafter a weaker version of the generalization of Karush-Kuh-Tucker in infinite horizon:

> Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ be a nonempty convex subset of
> $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and let $x^{*}\in Int\left(X\right)$. Let
> $f,g_{1},g_{2},...,g_{m}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be convex functions
> continuous at $x^{*}$ and term-to-term differentiable at $x^{*}$, i.e.
> such that the functions
> $f_{n,x^{*}}\left(x_{n}^{*}\right):=f\left(x^{*}\right)$ and
> $g_{j,n,x^{*}}\left(x_{n}^{*}\right):=g_{j}\left(x^{*}\right)$ are
> differentiable at $x_{n}^{*}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
> $j\in\left\{ 1,2,...,m\right\}$.
>
> (Qualification condition) Suppose that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}^{*}$
> and for all $x\in X$,
> $$x^{*}+P^{k}\left(x-x^{*}\right)=\left(x_{1},...,x_{k},x_{k+1}^{*},x_{k+2}^{*},...\right)\in X$$
> If there exist
> $\left(\lambda_{j}^{*}\right)_{j}\in\left(\mathbb{R}_{+}\right)^{\mathbb{N}}$
> such that
>
> $$\lambda_{j}^{*}g_{j}\left(x^{*}\right) =0,\:\forall j\in\left\{
> 1,2,...,m\right\} \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)$$
> $$f_{n,x^{*}}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}^{*}\right)+\sum_{j=1}^{m} \lambda_{j}^{*}g_{j,n,x^{*}}^{\prime}\left(x_{n}^{*}\right)=0,\:\forall
> n\in\mathbb{N} \quad \quad (2)$$
>
> (Sufficiency) Then $x^{*}$ is an optimal solution on $\Gamma:=\left\{
> \left(x_{i}\right)_{i}\in
> X\,:\,g_{1}\left(x\right)\leq0,...,g_{m}\left(x\right)\leq0\right\} :$
>
> $$f\left(x^{*}\right)=\underset{x\in\Gamma}{\inf}f\left(x\right)$$
>
> (Necessity) Besides, if $x^{*}$ is an optimal solution on $\Gamma$ and
> if the Slater condition $Int\left(\Gamma\right)\neq\emptyset$ is
> verified, then there exist unique
> $\left(\lambda_{j}^{*}\right)_{j}\in\left(\mathbb{R}_{+}\right)^{\mathbb{N}}$
> which verify the (Karush-Kuhn-Tucker) conditions (1) and (2).

The number of constraints has to be finite, but simple constraints like non-negativity constraints can be replaced by an equivalent restriction on the domain of the variables. For example, instead of the constraints $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\;x_n \geq 0$ on the domain $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$, one can take $X=(\mathbb{R}_+)^{\mathbb{N}}$, and the theorem applies.